# how to update the value of a react semantic UI progress bar by clicking it?

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I would like to be able to click on a [react semantic UI progress bar](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/progress/) to update its value.

Let's say I would click the exact middle of the bar, and its value would update to 50%.

Is that possible ?

```
  <Progress
  percent={value}
  />
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Well, I made this *ProgressClickable* component that wraps the *Progress* one.

Maybe it could be improved, but, hey, it works.

```
import React from "react";
import { Progress } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export const ProgressClickable = (props) => {

  const [mousePercent,setmousePercent] = React.useState(0);

  const updateMousePercent = (e) => {
    var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var width = rect.right - rect.left; //width of component
    var mouseX = e.clientX - rect.left; //pixel position of mouse within component
    var percent = mouseX / width * 100;
    setmousePercent(percent);
  }

  const handleOnMouseUp = (e) => {
    if (typeof props.onMouseUp === 'function') {
      props.onMouseUp(e,mousePercent);
    }
  }

  const cssStyle = {
    pointerEvents: props.disabled ? 'none' : 'auto',
    cursor: 'pointer'
  }

  return (
    <Progress
    percent={props.percent}
    size={props.size}
    onMouseMove={updateMousePercent}
    onMouseUp={handleOnMouseUp}
    disabled={props.disabled}
    style={cssStyle}
    />
  );
}
```